# Codecademy's python - Student Becomes the Teacher - 8/9

Tags: python

I guess many of you know the python codecademy course, 
and there is a specific section, that I saw, many people have trouble with,
the "Student Becomes the Teacher - 8/9"
the instructions are a bit unclear, 
and the problems met by others on the net are not exactly the same as mine here...

when I run this code, I get the correct answer - 83.8666666667
(I checked the result manually),
but I still get an error:
*"Oops, try again. get_class_average([alice]) resulted in an error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'dict'"*

WHAT AM I MISSING HERE??

Thanks...

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}


def average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    total = float(total)
    new_total = total / len(numbers)
    return new_total

#print(average(alice["homework"]))

def get_average(student):
    homework = average(student["homework"])
    quizzes = average(student["quizzes"])
    tests = average(student["tests"])
    return 0.1 * homework + 0.3 * quizzes + 0.6 * tests

#print get_average(tyler)

def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80:
        return "B"
    elif score >= 70:
        return "C"
    elif score >= 60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"

#print get_letter_grade(get_average(tyler))


def get_class_average(students):

    return average(students)

results = []
results.append(get_average(lloyd))
results.append(get_average(alice))
results.append(get_average(tyler))

print get_class_average(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the piece that I think you are missing (I too took that tutorial). If you make the results part of the `get_class_average` function i think that you will have more luck (example below)

```
def get_class_average(students):
    results=[]
    for student in students:
        results.append(get_average(student))
    return average(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function get_class_average([1, 2,3, 4]) takes a list of numbers. When you do get_class_average([alice]), you are passing a list of dictionary.
When the function tries to apply sum to a dict object, as in alice here, it throws that error.
Your program works fine for what it is intended for. e.g.

```
>>> sum([{}])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'dict'
```